# Characterisations of Projection Operators in Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, projection

Let $\mathbb{E}$ be a (real or complex) Banach space and let $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{E})$ be the Banach Space of continuous (bounded) linear operators from $\mathbb{E}$ into $\mathbb{E}$, with the operator norm.

An operator $P \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{E})$ is called projection if $P^2=P$.

Are there other characterisations of projection operators in Banach Spaces ?

Where can such characterisations be found ?

Comment: @Berci could you fix it ? If you don't mind

Comment: What do you mean by 'fixing it'? Posting as a response? There might be more characterizations, also I'm not aware of any specific references..

Comment: @Berci Your comment is unreadable! Don't you read the stuff you posted after posting?

Comment: @amsmath exactly

Comment: @Berci take a look again on your first post

Comment: Ahh.. I see (sorry I'm on mobile and comments are not formatted..) I can't edit that but can repost here

Comment: @Berci Oh, I see. What app are you using?

Comment: @Berci I also use mobile browser but I choose the full website not the mobile version

Comment: $P$ is projection iff $E=\ker(P-I)\oplus\ker P$ iff there exist disjoint closed subspaces $U, V$ such that $E=U\oplus V$ and $Pu=u, \ Pv=0$ for all $u\in U$ and $v\in V$.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: @Berci Thank, Merci, Danke.

Comment: @Berci you mean $I-P$ or $P-I$ ?

Comment: @Neilhawking They have the same kernel.